# Weka 3.9 with DBSCAN plugin optics (optics_dbscan) - Error: Problem evaluating clusterer: null

Tags: weka, dbscan, optics-algorithm

I have been using a [Weka OS](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/downloading.html) distribution with a *DBSCAN* clustering package called [optics_dbscan](http://weka.sourceforge.net/packageMetaData/optics_dbScan/1.0.0.html) (no longer maintained)for a few years but in the last few months it has stopped working, giving me the following error.
[image: Error Message]

I tried a range of Weka version both OSX and a range of *optics_dbscan* version and once or twice I got it to work but on a rerun it failed.

Laptop system changes since it worked: updated to MacOS Catalina

I support a large number of users on windows machines who have also experienced the same error.

**Actions taken:**

- Posted to an unresolved thread on the [Weka forum](https://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Problem-filtering-instances-null-using-Weka-3-6-11-td31885.html#a44696)
- Mailed the creators

Will report here if there is an update

If anyone has any assistance I would be grateful.

Comment: Why use it at all? It's known to be slow, and it's abandoned. So why are you trying to shoot yourself in the foot by using it?

Comment: Also, try using the **command line** or Java API get a stack trace of the error. GUI dialogs like this are not very helpful, and this is a *programming* web site, not a software support forum.

Comment: Thanks, @HasQUIT--Anony-Mousse thanks for your comments, and sorry for my delay. I will look at other algorithms and platforms suitable without an extensive programming component as this meets the requirements of my group. If you have some suggestions they would be welcome.